# Ruby App and AWS Beanstalk rake task not executed because script "check-for-bundle" is missing

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rake, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Ruby App in Beanstalk and I see that the `rake tasks` are not being executed because the command is looking for the below script:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-bundle
```

This is the portion of the log that shows the error:

```
[2017-01-31T14:53:21.715Z] INFO  [10750] - [Application update app-64d5-170131_155105@5/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_db_migration.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-31T14:53:22.293Z] INFO  [10750] - [Application update app-64d5-170131_155105@5/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_db_migration.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir
  + EB_SCRIPT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir
  + EB_SUPPORT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
  ++ export RACK_ENV=production
  ++ RACK_ENV=production
  ++ export RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=false
  ++ RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=false
  ++ export RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=false
  ++ RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=false
  ++ export BUNDLE_WITHOUT=test:development
  ++ BUNDLE_WITHOUT=test:development
  + RAKE_TASK=db:migrate
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/use-app-ruby.sh
  ++ . /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
  +++ CHRUBY_VERSION=0.3.9
  +++ RUBIES=()
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /opt/rubies ]]
  ++++ ls -A /opt/rubies
  +++ [[ -n ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ruby-2.0.0-p648
  ruby-2.1.10
  ruby-2.2.5
  ruby-2.3.1
  ruby-current ]]
  +++ RUBIES+=("$dir"/*)
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /.rubies ]]
  +++ unset dir
  +++ cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.ruby_version
  ++ chruby 2.3.1
  ++ case "$1" in
  ++ local dir match
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.5
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ match=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-current
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ [[ -z /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1 ]]
  ++ shift
  ++ chruby_use /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1 ''
  ++ [[ ! -x /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ export RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
  ++ RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
  ++ export RUBYOPT=
  ++ RUBYOPT=
  ++ export PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  ++ PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  +++ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -
  ++ eval 'export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby;
  export RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1;
  export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0";'
  +++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1
  +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1
  +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-bundle exec rake-task.rb db:migrate' webapp
  bundler: command not found: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-bundle
  Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
  + echo 'No db:migrate task in Rakefile, skipping database migration.'
  No db:migrate task in Rakefile, skipping database migration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My actual workaround:

```
#/.ebextensions/02_app.config
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: bundle exec rake db:migrate
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: can you explain ? is this an override of a standard EBS command?